# wordwrap php not working

Tags: php, mysql, line-breaks

I am trying to break a line after 20 characters which I am displaying from mysql database but it is not breaking anything.

**what I am getting**

> verylooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong

**what I need**

> verylooooooooooooooo
>
> oooooooooooooooooooo

```
 <?php
 $mydb = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM test  order by id DESC  ";
 $result = $mydb->query($sql);
 if (!$result) {
 echo $mydb->error;
 }
 ?> 

<html>
<body>
<div>
<?php
while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
echo "<div class='Dtitle'>".wordwrap($row['title'], 20, "<br />\n")."</div>";
}
$mydb->close ();
?>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your current result, and how does it differ from your expected result?

Comment: Can you post an example of what is actually happening, and what you expect?

Comment: what those 2 above me said...also, is the Dtitle class's style possibly removing or ignoring the line breaks created by wordwrap?

Comment: you need to add **true** as a parameter to the end in order to split words - see the manual page for more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `cut` argument to wordwrap.

Try:

```
echo "<div class='Dtitle'>".wordwrap($row['title'], 20, "<br />\n", true)."</div>";
                                                                    ^^^^
```

The PHP reference for wordwrap is [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try `style="word-break: break-all;"` or maybe `overflow:hidden`

Answer (score 0):

by default wordwrap does not split words you need to add true as a parameter to the end in order to split words - see the [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) for more

```
echo "<div class='Dtitle'>".wordwrap($row['title'], 20, "<br />\n",true)."</div>";
```